# Integral of $k$-homogeneous function on $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: calculus, integration

Let $h$ be a $k$-homogeneous function, and $\lambda > 0$. Show that:

$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \exp(-\lambda h(x))\,dx = \lambda^{-n/k} \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \exp(-h(x))\,dx \enspace .$$

**My attempt**:

By making the change of variable: $u = \lambda^{1/k}x$, it follows that:

$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \exp(-\lambda h(x))\,dx = \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \lambda^{-1/k}\exp(-\lambda h(\lambda^{-1/k}u))\,du \enspace .$$

Using the fact $h$ is $k$-homogeneous, it follows that:

$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \exp(-\lambda h(x))\,dx = \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \lambda^{-1/k} \exp(-h(u))\,du = \lambda^{-1/k} \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \exp(-h(u))\,du \enspace .$$

I don't know how to get the $\lambda^{-n/k}$ instead of $\lambda^{-1/k}$ scaling factor.

Comment: See my edits for proper usage in MathJax and LaTeX. The differential "dx" has a small space to the left and right, but in this case the space to the right is taken care of by the space that normally surrounds the "equals" sign.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that by performing a substitution for multiple variables, you have to multiply with the determinant of the Jacobian matrix of $u(x) = \lambda^{1/k} x$. Here, this is a diagonal matrix $\text{diag}(\lambda^{1/k},\dots,\lambda^{1/k})\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$, yielding $\lambda^{n/k}$ for the determinant and not just $\lambda^{1/k}$. If you substitute the other way around, then of course you have a minus sign in the exponent.

Comment: Arffffff of course. Thanks a lot! Completely missed it.